# Print stylesheet precedence

Tags: jquery, css, printing, stylesheet

I have inherited some legacy code which generates a ton of inline styles.

The client requires a print stylesheet which i am not sure will override the inline styles.

Assume not.

Would there be a way with jQuery to rip out all the inline styles whilst preserving the HTML structure prior to the print CSS being applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The client requires a print stylesheet
>   which i am not sure will override the
>   inlien styles.

No it won't override unless there is `!important` keyword used in the inline styles.

You can use the jQuery's [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method to remove inline styles like:

```
$('selector').removeAttr('style');
```

You can use the asterisk (`*`) in the selector to remove any inline styles from all elements but of course this will be slower unless you are sure about which elements to remove the style from.